# Error establishing a database connection - Docker Wordpress & mysql setup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, raspbian, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to set up a wordpress docker container on  a raspberry pi zero.
whey I browse IPv4 address of my raspberry pi zero i get following on the browser

> Error establishing a database connection

firstly RAM usage after running both containers

```
pi@web-server:~/website $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES 
e1cf99c5422b   website_wordpress   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   44 seconds ago   Up 28 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           wordpress_container  
ff2fdee991fc   website_db          "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   35 minutes ago   Up 30 seconds   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp   db
```

[image]

And finally my docker compose file "dockercompose.yaml"

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    db:
        build: ./db
        container_name: db
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: y4e8kane
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_USER: wordpress
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: y4e8kane
        networks:
            website_network:
                aliases:
                    - wordpress
    wordpress:
        build: .
        container_name: wordpress_container
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            website_network:
                aliases:
                    - wordpress
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSOWRD: y4e8kane
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
networks:
    website_network:
        name: website_network
volumes:
    db_data:
        driver: local
        name: db_data
```

I just have 2 dockerfiles in different dir, on same level di as docker-compose file I have one docker file related to wordpress and on {current_dir}/db i ahve another dockerfile related to mysql db

Comment: It is confused to use the same network aliases for 2 different services.
Could you try to rename them differently then try it again.

Comment: still the same i used alias as db